# LLN on the sample mean of an AR(1)

Tags: time-series, law-of-large-numbers

Given the following Law of Large numbers:
Let $X_t$ be a sequence of random variables with $E[X_t] = \mu, |cov(X_t,X_s)| \leq c * g^{|t-s|}$, where $g \in (0,1)$, then:
$$
\frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^{T} X_t \rightarrow \mu  
$$ in probability.

Moreover, given an AR(1) process:
$$
y_t = \alpha + g*y_{t-1} + u_t
$$
where |g| < 1.

Show that:
$$
\frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^{T} X_t \rightarrow \frac{mu}{1-g}
$$

I was thinking about going through showing the convergence to zero of the $V(\frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^{T} (X_t - \mu)$, but i don't know how to proceed. ANy suggestion?

Comment: Are you not lacking some details? You assume that $1/T\sum_{t = 1} ^T X_t \to \mu$ in probability for $T\to\infty$ and then you are asked to show that the same sum also converges to $\mu/(1-g)$? Also, where does $y_t$ come into the question?